# ServiceAccountKey.json can’t be downloaded

Tags: firebase

I’m trying to download the serviceAccountKey.json but it’s not showing the Generate new private key button.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

Comment: @pagep how does that link relate to the problem?  The "Generate new private key" button is missing.  Does your link solve that specific problem?

Comment: Issue also reported at https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1BL01PS7/p1656666884172359

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky yes it does? Well obviously it's a link to the steps you posted below? So  what do you don't understand?

Comment: Firebase technical support just emailed me and said the problem is resolved.  I confirmed the button is now back on the Firebase console.

Comment: Oh ok because I have been making it i was about to use Django

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternate method for generating new private key via Google Cloud console:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Select the project from the drop-down at the top of the screen
3. Go to table of contents (hamburger icon in top left)
4. Click "IAM & Admin"
5. Click "Service Accounts"
6. Find the service account whose name is "firebase-adminsdk"
7. Click its actions (3 vertical dots)
8. Click "Manage keys"
9. Click "ADD KEY"
10. Click "Create new key"
11. Select "JSON"
12. Click "Create"
13. It will download a JSON file equivalent to the one "Generate new private key" should give on the Firebase Console

source: https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1BL01PS7/p1656699811095319